# cannot deploy app to windows phone 8.1 device

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, deployment, windows-phone

When trying to deploy (any) windows phone 8.1 error I get the following error in VS2013:

> Error 3 Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Downloading package 'FF63DEA8-0A0C-4E52-B20F-84F390C30F32'': DirectoryNotFoundException - The system cannot find the path specified.

And in VS2015:

> Show Details Severity Code Description Project File Line Error Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Downloading package 'EB22551A-7F66-465F-B53F-E5ABA0C0574E (NativeMsVsMon)'': DirectoryNotFoundException - The system cannot find the path specified.

I can deploy app in visual studio 2012 , but in my case this is not an option because vs2012 does not support universal apps, so i cant open my project.

Phone is recognized by computer, it is unlocked, I've tried resetting import export settings, nothing works...

I have vs2013 update 4.

Comment: What do you mean "VS2013 does not support universal apps"? Does for me.

Comment: oops, my mistake... meant vs2012..

Comment: Have you tried deploying without debugging, by choosing deploy instead of pressing F5?

Comment: yes, deploy works.. but i want to debug..